# Java max and min of array returning wrong numbers

Tags: java, arrays, max, min

I'm having issues with calculating the max and min of an array. I'm looking for the max and min indices not the values they contain. My print out gives me 7 for max and 1 for min  but that is not correct. The max should be 1 and the min should be 6. I tried making the if statements in their own for loop but got the same result, I've looked at other codes but still can't seem to pinpoint where mine is going wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public static void displaySales (double[] data)
{
    double total = 0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i ++)
    {
        System.out.println("Week "+(i+1)+" total sales:"+data[i]);
        System.out.printf("Average daily sales week "+(i+1)+": %.2f\n\n", data[i]/7);
        total += data[i];

        if (max < data[i])
            max = i;
        if (min > data[i])
            min = i;

    }
    double avgWeeklySales = total/data.length;

    System.out.printf ("Total sales: %.2f\n", total);
    System.out.printf ("Average weekly sales: %.2f\n", avgWeeklySales);
    System.out.println ("Week with highest sales: "+ (max+1));
    System.out.println ("Week with lowest sales: "+ (min+1));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the indices having the min and max values in the `data` array. This means you should keep track of both the min/max index and min/max value.

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int minIndex = 0;
int maxIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
    System.out.println("Week "+(i+1)+" total sales:"+data[i]);
    System.out.printf("Average daily sales week "+(i+1)+": %.2f\n\n", data[i]/7);
    total += data[i];

    if (max < data[i]) {
        maxIndex = i;
        max = data[i];
    }
    if (min > data[i]) {
        minIndex = i;
        min = data[i];
    }
}
```

Finally you should print `minIndex+1` and `maxIndex+1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to put the value of `data[i]` and not `i`.

```
    if (max < data[i])
        max = data[i];
    if (min > data[i])
        min = data[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to update the max and min values with actual values (not the indexes), then store the index in a different variable. Also, the comparison should be reversed

```
if (max > data[i]) {
    max = data[i];
    maxIndex = i;
}
if (min < data[i]) {
    min = data[i];
    minIndex = i;
}
```

At the end print the index values. (Also don't forget to declare them)

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinMaxTest {
    static void minMax(int[] arr){
        int sum=0,min=0,max=0,ch=0;
        int[] temp = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            sum=sum+arr[i];
        }
        //temp=sum-arr[0];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            temp[i]=sum-arr[i];
        }
        //sort the array, 0 is minimum element index and array length - 1 index is maximum element index
        for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<temp.length-1-i;j++){
                if(temp[j]>temp[j+1]){
                    ch=temp[j];
                    temp[j] = temp[j+1];
                    temp[j+1] = ch;
                }
            }
        }
        /*for(int i: temp){
            System.out.println(i);
        }*/

        System.out.println(temp[0]+" "+temp[arr.length-1]);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("fd:" + 3/6);
                Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("enter the size of array");
                int n = scn.nextInt();
                int[] arr = new int[n];
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                    arr[i] = scn.nextInt();
                }
                minMax(arr);
                scn.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Why is this preferable and why does it solve the problem?

Comment: it provides min and max element index.

Comment: Then write something that says that in your answer. Your answer should be useful for people who do not have the exact specific same problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Comment: it solves the problem as states: I'm having issues with calculating the max and min of an array. I'm looking for the max and min indices not the values they contain.

Comment: So write that in the answer and explain why it does that.